# Rubyの２次元配列から指定値を取得したい

Tags: ruby

ruby(ver2)の勉強中です。　２次元配列から指定値を取得する際の
コードイメージがつかず、どなたかご教授頂ければと存じます。

２次元配列の内容

```
[
  ["北海道", "ヤマダ", "２２歳"],
  ["東京", "タナカ", "２３歳"],
  ["大阪", "サトウ", "２２歳"]
]
```

希望の動き

```
1:getsで指定値を入力
2:北海道で検索すると、["北海道", "ヤマダ", "２２歳"]の配列を取得
3:２２歳で検索すると["北海道", "ヤマダ", "２２歳"]と["大阪", "サトウ", "２２歳"]を取得
```

恐れ入りますが、よろしくお願いします

Answer (score 1, accepted):

実用的コードかは置いておくとして、とりあえずこんな感じのコードで希望の動きができるかと思います。

これでイメージはつかめますでしょうか。

```
search_word = gets.chomp

result = []

data_array = [
  ["北海道", "ヤマダ", "２２歳"],
  ["東京", "タナカ", "２３歳"],
  ["大阪", "サトウ", "２２歳"]
]

data_array.each {|data|
  result.push data if data.include? search_word
}

p result
```

参考サイト

each
http://ref.xaio.jp/ruby/classes/array/each

push
http://ref.xaio.jp/ruby/classes/array/push

include
http://ref.xaio.jp/ruby/classes/array/include

Comment: 頂いた内容で想定通りの動きになりました　ありがとうございます！